# Copiar estructura de tabla tipo

Tags: sql

BD: Sql server 2014

Tengo una tabla "User-defined Table Type" lo que necesito es copiar su estructura (columnas) a una tabla temporal

Comment: ¿Nos podrías dar datos más específicos? ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla? ¿Qué has investigado o intentado?

Comment: copiar sus columnas

Answer (score 2):

Dado que no hay mucha información, te puedo recomendar lo siguiente:

Puedes usar insert select para copiar toda su estructura y datos de la tabla:

```
INSERT INTO #nuevatabla
SELECT * FROM origentabla;
```

Si deseas Sólo la estructura:

```
SELECT * Into #Nombredetabla 
From TablaOrigen
```

Recuerda que #TablaTemporal es de tipo local y ##TablaTemporal es de tipo global.